# 100% CPU Usage while running TCP server application

Tags: c#, cpu-usage, tcplistener

I have a tcp server application which accepts tcp clients in more number and receives continuous messages from all the connected clients.

```
public void KeepListening()
    {
        while (IsRunning)
        {
                try
                {
                        Thread.Sleep(20);
                        if (tcpListener.Pending())
                        {
                            //Get the socket obtained from the tcpListener
                            TcpClient _Client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                            NetworkStream ns = _Client.GetStream();
                            Thread.Sleep(20);
                            if (Stop_Status == false)
                            {
                                if (_Client.Connected)
                                {
                                    int DataBytes = _Client.Available;
                                    byte[] data = new byte[DataBytes];
                                    if (ns.DataAvailable == true)
                                    {
                                        ns.Read(data, 0, DataBytes);
                                        string Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
                                        string[] KeyCodes = Key.Split(',');
                                        if (Key != "" && ((KeyCodes[0].StartsWith("i"))))
                                            ProcessClient(_Client, KeyCodes[0], Key);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ns.Flush();
                            }
                        }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
        }
    }


    void ProcessClient(TcpClient _Client, string Key,string Msg)
    {
        try
        {
            if (hashTable_Users.Count > 0)
            {
                if (hashTable_Users.Contains(Key))
                {
                    hashTable_Users.Remove(Key);
                }
            }
            hashTable_Users.Add(Key, _Client);
            hashusers = hashTable_Users.Count;
            this.MessageFromClient(Key, serverPortNo.ToString(), Msg);

            //StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_Client.GetStream());
            //sw.WriteLine("1");
            //sw.Flush();

            object[] objarr = new object[5];
            objarr[0] = _Client;
            objarr[1] = Key;
            Thread ReceiveFromClient = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ReceiveFromClients));
            ReceiveFromClient.Start(objarr);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
   public void ReceiveFromClients(object obj)
    {
            object[] objarr = (object[])obj;
            TcpClient _Client = (TcpClient)objarr[0];
            NetworkStream ns = _Client.GetStream();
            while (IsRunning)
            {
                if (Stop_Status == false)
                {
                    if (_Client.Connected)
                    {
                        if (ns.DataAvailable)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                int numBytesRead = _Client.Available;
                                byte[] data = new byte[numBytesRead];
                                ns.Read(data, 0, numBytesRead);
                                string MsgReceived = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
                                string clientKey = objarr[1].ToString();
                                this.MessageFromClient(clientKey, serverPortNo.ToString(), MsgReceived);
                            }
                            catch
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ns.Flush();
                }
            }
    }
```

`KeepListening()` is used to accept the clients which send the request. `ProcessClient()` and `ReceiveFromClients()` are used to receive the messages from the clients.

This application is using 100% cpu.

Please suggest me what to do to decease the cpu utilization?

Comment: To decrease CPU utilization use Profiler to find out which piece of code and which line of code does consume most CPU resources.

Then reconsider your application and re-write your code that takes too much resources.

Comment: It is not surprise. You thread sleep only 20 ms between working cycle. I.e it works permanently.

Comment: You should write proper async tcp server and not poll. Use BeginReceive and BeginAccept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking into your code, ReceiveFromClients is consuming most of CPU, because of while (IsRunning) and in that you are reading if only data is available.

To solve this, dont check IsAvailabele, call ReadMethod which blocks the thread until ReadTimeOut occurs or some data has been read. Based on the number of bytes received, process your data.

Comment: Please consider rewriting your code if it isn't just experimental. Sleep has no place in server/client code. Make use of async socket programming.

Comment: Hi Sudhakar, If I run a single instance of TCP Server the cpu utilization is in between 50- 70 %. But If I am running two instances of servers(Same IP, Diff Port) then again cpu is consuming 100% memory. What to do?

Comment: Hi BLueM, May I have the working examples of Async communication?

Comment: I'll try the same for my java app. I'm also checking `reader.ready()` it consume %12 percent CPU. TCP client app uses almost nothing. But TCP server socket consume more, most probably because of this .ready check. If this is the case, the use use of this ready , hasBytesToRead ...kinda methods are not so efficient. (In this type of use)

Comment: I've applied this and started observing now. The drawback is `ReadTimeOut` is a must in this method because you're reading even there's no data available.

Comment: I've never faced 100% CPU but after several hours I noticed that using timeout and not checking available bytes indefinitely dramatically reduced CPU usage.  From %11-12 percent to %0.x-%2.y percent.  If read timeout defined still checking IsAvailable otherwise using going for read catch timeout based on settings. We might also consider checking IsAvailable less often to let CPU get breath but this might cause comm baud rate. It looks this is the best to go for now.

Answer (score 0):

> Please suggest me what to do to decease the cpu utilization?

Well this looks like a bad start:

```
while (IsRunning)
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

If you're repeatedly getting exceptions, you'll never know about it - and just keep looping. You've got another empty catch block, too... you *really* shouldn't catch everything and just keep going, without even logging.

Likewise here:

```
while (IsRunning)
{
    if (Stop_Status == false)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ns.Flush();
    }
}
```

If `IsRunning` is true, and `Stop_Status` is false, that's just going to tight loop, calling `Flush` repeatedly...